# Eliminate flickering from a user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have this user control. When resizing, some of the components flicker noticeably.

During user resizing, the control itself performs some inner resizing, which could be the source of the flickering.

Even if I use double buffering, there is no improvement.

I found on this site a solution:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | 0x2000000;// Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
        return cp;
    }
}
```

which works fine, but unfortunately at consumer level only, so it has to be included in every form which consumes the control.

Is there a way to implement this from inside the control, instead of forcing it on each user? Maybe at run time when the control can access the parent form?

Comment: This is a good reason to always have a custom base form.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?